# Deserializing XML CDATA into string variable with RestSharp

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, xml-deserialization, restsharp

I'm trying to take an RSS feed and deserialize it into a list of rssEntry objects.

```
var Client = new RestClient("url here");
Request = new RestRequest { RequestFormat DataFormat.Xml };
var response = Client.Execute<Channel>(Request);
return response.Data.Item;
```

This fills everything in except content which contains CDATA

Channel.cs

```
 public class Channel
 {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string AtomLink { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastBuildDate { get; set; }
    public string Generator { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public string UpdatePeriod { get; set; }
    public int UpdateFrequency { get; set; }
    public RssItems Item { get; set; }
}
```

Item.cs

```
public class Item 
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
        public string Creator { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string CommentRss { get; set; }
        public int SlashComments { get; set; }
  }
```

I'm open to using something other than RestSharp, but I was trying it out for this hoping it would be a nice easy solution.

Currently any field with CDATA is returned as null.

Comment: that could be a bug in RestSharp. if you can provide sample XML and class defs in the google group I can troubleshoot http://groups.google.com/group/restsharp

Comment: also, you don't need to specify requestformat unless you're sending XML as the request body (rare)

Comment: Thanks, I removed the RequestFormat and posted to the google group.

Comment: My variable named content would match to something in the rss that is <content:encoded> which turns into <encoded> so content didn't match during deserialization.  There was no issue with restsharp, just my naming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I read through the xml in the RSS feed and I named the variables in the items class content.  The actual item element in the rss feed was content:encoded.

Changing this variable to Encoded fixed it, completely my own fault.

```
public class Item 
{
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Link { get; set; }
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public DateTime PubDate { get; set; }
        public string Creator { get; set; }
        public string Category { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Encoded { get; set; }
        public string Guid { get; set; }
        public string CommentRss { get; set; }
        public int SlashComments { get; set; }
}
```